# Templated URLs in Prometheus End Point with Jersey and Micrometer

Tags: java, prometheus, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am trying to integrate micrometer in a spring application built using Jersey REST. I am using Spring Boot 1.5.

When I have a pure Spring REST APIs (using Spring Web Annotations), prometheus results are displayed as below

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/v2/api/greeting/{name}",} 18.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/v2/api/greeting/{name}",} 0.39309228
```

But for the APIs built using Jersey, the prometheus metrics are not templated.

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/v1/api/greeting/Jersey_1",} 1.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/v1/api/greeting/Jersey_1",} 0.043685372
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/v1/api/greeting/Jersey_2",} 1.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/v1/api/greeting/Jersey_2",} 0.006280183
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/v1/api/greeting/Jersey_3",} 1.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/v1/api/greeting/Jersey_3",} 0.006258448
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/v1/api/greeting/Jersey_4",} 1.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/v1/api/greeting/Jersey_4",} 0.006635791
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/v1/api/greeting/Jersey_5",} 1.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/v1/api/greeting/Jersey_5",} 0.006313993
```

Looks like there is an open issue with micrometer listed at https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/486 which causes this issue with jersey. A remedy is mentioned at https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/486#issuecomment-372446968. When I add spring.jersey.type=filter, none of the actuator APIs work. Neither prometheus end point works.

I do not want un-templated URLs appearing in Prometheus end point. Since my API can have infinitely many combinations (many names in above examples), it will create large metrics data and in turn prometheus server will have tones of metrics.

Any help here is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created [a sample to reproduce the problem from your description](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/tree/so-52670641) but failed to reproduce it. I can see URI templates are being used in the Prometheus scrape endpoint (`/management/prometheus`) as follows:

```
# HELP http_server_requests_seconds  
# TYPE http_server_requests_seconds summary
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/prometheus",} 1.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/prometheus",} 0.062559545
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/hello/{name}",} 1.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/hello/{name}",} 0.02323862
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="UNKNOWN",} 1.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="UNKNOWN",} 0.050339909
# HELP http_server_requests_seconds_max  
# TYPE http_server_requests_seconds_max gauge
http_server_requests_seconds_max{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/prometheus",} 0.062559545
http_server_requests_seconds_max{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/hello/{name}",} 0.02323862
http_server_requests_seconds_max{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="UNKNOWN",} 0.050339909
```

I guess there might be some misconfiguration in your project or I might miss some requirement(s) from your description.

UPDATE:

Based on the comment, disabling Web MVC metrics will provide cleaner result as follows:

```
# HELP http_server_requests_seconds  
# TYPE http_server_requests_seconds summary
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/hello/{name}",} 1.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/hello/{name}",} 0.032691223
# HELP http_server_requests_seconds_max  
# TYPE http_server_requests_seconds_max gauge
http_server_requests_seconds_max{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/hello/{name}",} 0.032691223
```

I also updated the sample in the following commit: https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/commit/14ff838c48cea0c38cf12eeec8e7b211dffe2c50

Comment: hey thanks for your help. Only difference I see is, micrometer version. I am using 1.0.3 whereas your project uses 1.0.6. There is one problem I have observed with 1.0.6, even I could see it using your project is, it aggregates the URLs with UNKNOWN. `http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="UNKNOWN",} 1.0`

Comment: @user1401472 Thanks for the feedback! I updated my answer to resolve it.

Comment: You could be right in disabling the web mvc metrics. But my problem is, I am not seeing the templated URLs at all. So in my example - I dont see any metric with URI as "/v1/api/greeting/{name}". Let me dig more into it to find out the differences.

Comment: Missing micrometer-jersey2 dependency!. Thanks a lot for your help.